# Monitor squid proxy usage by subnet

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm building a router/proxy box for a nonprofit organization. They have five internal departments, and I have assigned each department to a separate subnet. All web traffic goes out through a squid proxy that is running on my box.

I am currently using sarg to generate html usage reports for squid, and that has been working well so far. But the one essential feature that is missing is the ability to see a total of how much quota each subnet/department has used for the reporting period.

I have looked at quite a few other squid report tools aside from sarg, and none seem to have this ability.

Any recommendations on the easiest way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you simply use a heirarchy? one proxy per subnet, (with no cache, it simply forwards all requests to your cache), and each one responsible for logging/reporting on its own subnet... would be fairly easy to duplicate config once the first one is working.. dunno. Feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Try ntop, it create network graph per interfaces, and you can filter by subnets